# Literal String methods versus Object methods

Tags: java, string-literals

I have seen both versions, so I'm just wondering, is there any real difference between these two expressions? Which is the conventional way of writing it?

```
"hello".equals(myString)
 myString.equals("hello")
```

EDIT: **This portion of my question makes it not a duplicate**

Why is it good that `"hello".equals(myString)` doesn't throw an error? Wouldn't you want the caller to be responsible for using a null string? By this logic, wouldn't using `myString.equals("hello")` enforce cleaner code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is the first, because it cannot throw an exception.

The second way throws a `NullPointerException` if `myString` is `null`.

> Why is it good that "hello".equals(myString) doesn't throw an error? Wouldn't you want the caller to be responsible for using a null string?

You are correct that it is a good thing for programming errors to be detected as quickly as possible, so sometimes exceptions are a good thing. If `myString` should not be `null`, I would throw an exception for that explicitly, rather than relying on `myString.equals("hello");` throwing an exception. For example

```
public void someMethod(String myString) {
    if (myString == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if ("hello".equals(myString))
        // do something
}
```

This code is completely equivalent to using `if (myString.equals("hello"))`, but the intent is clearer, and there's no chance of another programmer coming along, not realising why you didn't put the literal first, and swapping it around.

Comment: [`Objects.requireNonNull(myString)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T))…

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the first version will never raise a `NullPointerException`, if `myString` is `null` it will return false.